# Need to show a SQLite query in descending order

Tags: android, sqlite

I want to make a query such that the result will be shown in <strike>indistinct</strike> descending order.

For example, assume column ID has six rows. I need an query that shows me the list of IDs <strike>indistinct</strike> descending from 6 to 1.

**EDIT:** Based on the first post's text, the question is how do display query results in descending order. For instance, given the IDs

```
ID
--
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

Desired results:

```
ID
--
 6
 5
 4
 3
 2
 1
```

Comment: I don't even understand your question and what exactly you are trying to do, could you be more explicit and clarify.

Comment: Consider adding the query you executed to the post

Comment: @notfed: Please be mindful of the fact that not everyone who posts here has English as their first or primary language, and be more polite in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

You need to add an `ORDER BY ID DESC` to your select statement.

[ORDER BY](http://www.1keydata.com/sql/sqlorderby.html)

Comment: `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CHALLENGE + " WHERE " + KEY_ACTIVE + " = '" + active.trim() + "' ORDER BY " + KEY_DATE + " ASC", null);` where KEY_DATE is of type TEXT in my Sqlite Db and in `MM/dd/yyyy/ format and it's not working. Please help... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40129782/why-is-the-order-by-not-working-in-a-sqlite-query

Comment: you saved my day..Thanks +1 for that

Answer (score 15):

Use following statement....

```
select * from YOUR_TABLE_NAME ORDER BY ID  DESC;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write like this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME+" 
                WHERE "+STATUS+" = "+"'0'" + " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 10", null);
return cursor ;
```

Comment: This is literally opening yourself to SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

/* In the most simple and basic way, you can write it as */

SELECT ID
FROM your_table_name
ORDER BY ID DESC;

/* This should work fine with your problem and should give you your desired output */