# Why is the ORDER BY not working in a Sqlite query

Tags: android, sqlite

Sqlite table creation in Android:

```
// Contacts table name
private static final String TABLE_CHAL = "CD";

// Contacts Table Columns names
private static final String KEY_ID = "id";
private static final String KEY_CHAL = "chal";
private static final String KEY_DATE = "date";

String CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CHAL + "("
        + KEY_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," + KEY_CHAL + " TEXT,"
        + KEY_DATE + " TEXT)";
db.execSQL(CREATE_CONTACTS_TABLE);
```

Querying (Order by KEY_DATE):

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CHAL + " ORDER BY [" + KEY_DATE + "] ASC", null);
```

The above doesn't seem to be working.

Do I have to convert the `KEY_DATE` into date before doing the order.

Comment: Why did you put square brackets in the ORDER BY clause?

Comment: I am coming from a SQL background so I am thinking I should put the bracket incase I have a column which has space.

Comment: What's the format of dates you're putting in that column?

Comment: fetch the data in arraylist and then use collection sorting technique

Comment: 'Mm/dd/yyyy' format

Comment: So it's get sorted alphabetically in your MM/dd/yyyy format which is likely not the order you want. Either store in a sortable format such as epoch timestamp or yyyy-MM-dd to avoid having, or do datetime conversion in your query.

Comment: Yeah i was going to do that but was checking to see if there was a better way. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Check out the proper date/time formats for SQLite (a.k.a. TimeStrings): https://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html

Comment: How can I properly format the column before querying?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a new column with the existing `KEY_DATE` column and saved it in a `yyyy-mm-ddd` format. Then I updated my query to `date("+KEY_FORMAT_DATE+")";` and it worked for me.

Comment: Thanks to everyone who guided me toward my solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
SELECT * FROM cd ORDER BY datetime(substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2))
```

Comment: `date` in this case would be the `KEY_DATE` column?

Comment: Also, replace `KEY_DATE` above in the query with `datetime(substr(KEY_DATE, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(KEY_DATE, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(KEY_DATE, 1, 2))`?

Comment: tried this: `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CHAL + " WHERE " + KEY_ACTIVE + " = '" + active.trim() + "' ORDER BY " + datetime(substr(KEY_DATE, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(KEY_DATE, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(KEY_DATE, 1, 2)) + " ASC", null);` and I got an error in the `datetime` and also in the `substr`

Comment: @Si8 Those are SQL functions, and belong into the SQL statement.

Comment: Ok so I don't be able to use it in a cursor I am guessing?

Comment: Why not? SQL functions are perfectly valid in statements. Just try the query I gave you, then when it's working replace the variables.

Comment: So it will be: `db.execSQL("SELECT * FROM cd ORDER BY datetime(substr(date, 7, 4) || '-' || substr(date, 4, 2) || '-' || substr(date, 1, 2))");`

Comment: Ok I will try it out and let you know. Thanks.

Comment: So what I did was create a new column and formatted in YYYY-MM-DD (2016-05-20) and updated my query to this: `Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CHAL + " ORDER BY date(" + KEY_FORMATTED_DATE + ") ASC", null);` but same issue

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace yours with this:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_CHAL + " ORDER BY " + KEY_DATE + "ASC", null);
```

Comment: Nope... not working. I thin it is because it's a string. I might have to convert to DATE first?