# Display data from CursorAdapter in ascending order of Id in a ListView?

Tags: java, android, simplecursoradapter

I am  retrieving data from my sqlite database table (which has Id and text) as `Cursor` and setting it to `ListView` using `SimpleCursorAdapter` as below:

```
Cursor cursor = rawQuery("select IdColumn, TextColumn from Comments  where whereArgs ",
            new String[]{whereArgs});
 adapter = new android.support.v4.widget.SimpleCursorAdapter(context,
            android.R.layout.two_line_list_item,
            cursor,
            new String[]{"IdColumn", "TextColumn"},
            new int[]{android.R.id.text1, android.R.id.text2},
            0);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

The output is displayed as follows:

[image]

I want the data to displayed in ascending order of Id like this;

1

2

3

4

5

6

.....so on.

Please help!

Edit: I am newbie to programming.

Comment: Could you show us your *SQL Query* ?

Comment: Hi @JayRathodRJ! Thank you for your concern! the solution provided by ESoares is working fine. I have updated my sql query as follows: select IdColumn, TextColumn from Comments  where whereArgs order by IdColumn.

Comment: I am not understanding the reason for voting down this question! I am trying to learn new subjects and have already posted what I have progressed so far in this assignment. Are we all supposed to be genius here at SO?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add in your SQL query a `ORDER BY ID ASC`.

Related: [Need to show a SQLite query in descending order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900351/need-to-show-a-sqlite-query-in-descending-order)

Comment: read a question 1st. his/hear want to **show a data on ASC order** *not to* **DESC order**

Comment: Fixed, just change the order by to be ASC (ascending).

Comment: gooooood **:)**

Comment: Sure, I will try this now.